# Как добраться до дальнего родителя в JS

Tags: javascript, pure_js

Как добраться до дальнего родителя в JS? Чтобы этот код выглядел более круто.

```
  for(var i=0; i < carlingFox.length; ++i){
    var el = sexturyFox[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
     el.style.background = 'red'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function closest(el, cl) {
var elem = el;

while(elem.className != cl) {
    if(elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'html') return false;
    elem = elem.parentNode;
}
return elem;
```

}

Аргументы ел - элемент, кл - класс элемента который нужно найти.
Если в дом не оказалось эл с таким классом, возвращает false;

Comment: Я бы еще добавил проверку на тип родителя: искать по имени класса или по тегу.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать функцию вроде:

```
function gt(node, indx) {
    var parent;
    for (var i = 0; i <= indx; i++) {
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return(node);
}
```

и вызывать по индексу (0 - первый родитель)

```
gt(sexturyFox[i], 3).style.background = 'red';
```

[Например](http://jsfiddle.net/cxZ9n/)

Comment: 1 -  Неудобно считать индексы, удобней по какому то идентификатору

Comment: @markuper тоже об этом думал, но там может быть несколько одинаковых вложенных, поэтому лучше цепляться к айди или классу.

Comment: **неудобно в любом случае**, потому что если вы пытаетесь **так** обходить DOM-узлы, вы явно делаете что-то неправильно, просто добавьте идентификатор, выигрыш в быстродействии, удобстве, читабельности, что ещё нужно?

Comment: Это уж вопрос к автору, а не ко мне =)